# 'Error: No provider for AngularFirestore!' - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

I am following the installation [guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) to setup AngularFire2 in my Ionic 3 App.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "angularfire2/firestore";

...

imports = [
    ....
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    ....
]
```

**component.ts**

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

...

constructor( private afDB: AngularFirestore ) { }
```

**package.json**

```
"@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",
"firebase": "^5.9.3",
```

I am getting this error in console:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestore!

Comment: When adding  AngularFirestore in providers I get: ReferenceError: AngularFirestore is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error.

What I was doing bad:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "angularfire2/firestore";
```

What is working now:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```